# sound on/off in an app using radio button

Tags: android, audio, radio-button, mute

I am working on a game, and want to switch sound to on and off using radio button. The sounds are running in my app in other options. when sound off radio button is pressed it should mute the sound until and unless sound  on pressed. Can anyone help me out to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mp.start();
//for Mute
mp.setvolume(0,0);
//& Unmute or full volume
mp.setvolume(0,1);

Comment: this works fine when working on a single layout. but won't work when i  move from one page to other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
AudioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```

..this should mute the default music stream. Pass in false to enable it again.

Comment: it gives me force close error as soon as i click options button,

Comment: AudioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);     i used it, it successfully mute the sound. but when i pass false to enable it it doesnot work.. Help needed again!!!!

Comment: You might have to get the stream volume before the mute and then try setting the value back to this afterwards with the getStreamVolume and setStreamVolume methods

Answer (score 0):

To disable sound you set it to True. To re enable sound, you set it to false.
You can have a button for each or a toggle button.